# Shell Script: how to check multiple groups if they exists and display in echo

Tags: linux, shell, rhel7

This is my current code:

```
 if [ $(getent group administrators) ]; then
   echo "Group exists"
 else
   echo "Group does not exist"
 fi
```

My questions are:

- how do I improve it by making it such that I can include more groups to display?
- and display the group e.g administrators, appears in the echo like: The group administrators, students exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `&&` to test multiple conditions.

```
if [ $(getent group administrators) ] && [ $(getent group students) ]
then
    echo The groups administrators and students exit
else
    echo The groups administrators and students do not both exist
fi
```